# SQL Uniqueidentifier to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to achieve this in SQL Server:

```sql
exec proc_sample ''
```

but there is an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier.
> Heres my sample proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_sample]
( @ID uniqueidentifier )
AS BEGIN
IF
@ID IS NULL
OR @ID = ''
SELECT * FROM table1
ELSE
SELECT * FROM table2
END
```

I know that the issue is the OR @ID = '', but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The error is *literally* telling you the problem. `''` isn't a valid `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: is there a way that we can convert this '' ? Sorry am a bit new to SQL and im hoping you could help me. thanks

Comment: `''` can't be converted to a `uniqueidentifier` no, the values are completely different. I don't know why you're using a `uniqueidentifier` here anyway; it seems like you'd be better off with a `bit` and passing `0` or `1` and then running the relevant query.

Comment: Convert to what? This isn't a valid GUID string. If you want to make the parameter optional, pass a NULL

Comment: my goal is the parameter should be either NULL or ' ' (blank).

Comment: Also, the sort of "blank guid" is '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

Comment: That's not a blank,there's no such thing in SQL, the language. It's a very specific string value, the empty string, which has no representation as a GUID or an int, or a decimal. If you wanted to specify a `zero` value, it would be a GUID with all values set to 0.

Comment: To put into perspective, a `uniqueidentifier` can store 2¹²⁸ values! You don't need that many for something which only needs to be what is effectively a "yes or no"

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What is the *real* problem you want to solve by passing an empty string to a non-string parameter?

Comment: Can't you just skip the `OR @ID = ''`, since that value can't be passed to the routine anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...just change the input @ID parameter to a character type

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_sample]
( @ID varchar(10))
AS BEGIN
IF
@ID IS NULL
OR @ID = ''
SELECT * FROM table1
ELSE
SELECT * FROM table2
END
```

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to pass a NULL parameter into the procedure then it should be assigned the default value NULL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_sample]
( @ID uniqueidentifier=NULL )
AS BEGIN
IF
@ID IS NULL
OR @ID = ''
SELECT * FROM table1
ELSE
SELECT * FROM table2
END
```